# Image importing library for android

Tags: android, facebook, dropbox, instagram, picasa

I am looking for a library which simplifies retrieving images from various social networks (including authentication flow).

In my app the user should be able to choose images from Facebook, Picasa, Flickr, Instagram and DropBox.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not a full ready to use library solution that fits your needs. Anyway here are the reference libraries you can wrap in a kind of authentication management system and you can handle the image retrieval in a factory.

- Facebook + Instagram + Other social networks | [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE)
- Dropbox | [Official SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android)
- Picasa | (Unfortunately, the [OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java))
- Flickr | [Flickrj-android](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/)

To make your life easier with the oauth stuff and loading images in lists, grids and so on, here you have two libraries from the awesome Square team that are a must have for a project like yours. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) & [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).